# React-Native Pressable component randomly stops working

Tags: react-native, pressable

I am having a strange issue where a pressable component with a hit slop of 'top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50, right: 50' randomly stops working.

I am currently using Expo 39.0.0 and React-Native 39.0.4.

Has anyone encountered any similar issues?